# Como colar texto na mesma coluna do Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Copio dados de um PDF e gostaria que cada linha seja colado tudo na mesma coluna "A", pois depois tenho uma macro que faz todo o trabalho de dividir em colunas que funciona muito bem.

No meu computador o Excel cola em uma só coluna, assim que copio do PDF, porem no PC de quem vai usar a planilha hoje começou a colar uma parte na coluna A e divide o restante nas colunas B, C e D, até ontem ele colava na coluna A.

Alguem sabe como forçar que tudo seja colado somente na coluna A?

Answer (score -1):

A opção de colagem especial talvez serviria para o procedimento...

[image: Word - Opções de Colagem]

Comment: Não quero converter linha em coluna, quero que cada linha do PDF fique somente na coluna A. Antes ele colava em uma coluna só. Agora toda vez que cola ele já usa as colunas A, B, C e D.